# How to stop propagation in all controls in a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, event-bubbling, jquery-3

Since I found annoying the caching of a modal in angularjs and bootstrap, I found this article "[$modal caching](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1193)" to add a kind of version into the url of the modal and in that way avoid the caching of new changes in the content of the modal, but since I did that when I click on the button to open the modal or any control inside the modal I always get this script error 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined at ih.js:223` from jquery-3.1.0 library on line 223.

**Button to open the edit department (mine)**

```
    $scope.editDepartment = function(id){
        var uibModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl : '../webproject/modal_department.html?bust=' + Math.random().toString(36).slice(2),
            controller : 'DepartmentModalController',
            scope: $scope
        });
        return uibModalInstance.result.then(function(department){ 
            $scope.department = department;
        });
    }
```

**jQuery method from jQuery library where it is produced the error**

```
Messaging.prototype.addEventListener = function() {
  var func,
    _this = this;
  func = function(evt) {
    return _this.receiveMessage(evt);
  };
  if (this.window.addEventListener) {
    this.window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

      var target = event.target;

      while (target && target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'a') {
        target = target.parentNode;
        if (!target) { return; }
      }

      var url = target.href;
      if(url.indexOf('afsrc=')>-1||url.indexOf('jdoqocy.com')>-1||url.indexOf('kqzyfj.com')>-1||url.indexOf('tkqlhce.com')>-1||url.indexOf('anrdoezrs.net')>-1||url.indexOf('dpbolvw.net')>-1) {
          chrome.extension.sendRequest({action:"suppressToolbar"});
      }

    });
    return this.window.addEventListener("message", func, false);
  } else if (this.window.attachEvent) {
    return this.window.attachEvent("onmessage", func);
  }
};
```

I debugged the code and from the moment that I click on the button to open the modal, on the save button that I have inside my modal, or any other control like a simple checkbox or radiobutton it goes to this code from Jquery `while (target && target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'a')` and I think (correct me if I am wrong) a bubbling is occurring. It starts to evaluate all HTML elements that contains the control until arrive to the element #document which does not have the property tagName and it generates the error.

I started to place on all controls the `onclick="event.stopPropagation();"` which works well but I started to pollute all the controls from modal.

Is there a way to stop the propagation in all inner controls from modal or in the code to open the modal  or can I stop the bubbling from CSS?

**EDIT**

The error was due to some chrome extensions that I installed recently. I uninstalled them and restarted the browser and the problem was gone.

Comment: Give all your modals a shared class (if they don't have one already), and then just put this in JS: `$(".modalclass").on("click",function(e){e.stopPropagation();});` (preferably before all the other event-handlers for the modals). *If you have modals dynamically added, use this instead: `$(document).on("click",".modalclass",function(e){e.stopPropagation();});`*

Comment: Create a demo in plunker that reproduces problem. Have never run into problems using `$uibModal`

Comment: It's not clear. Is `Messaging.prototype.addEventListener` 
(a) something that you added to fix your caching issue?; or 
(b) something that worked before and has stopped working when you changed something else?

Comment: @Roamer-1888. No, the code that you mention is from jquery library. I copied that code and I said where the error is produced

Comment: Thank you. At least the question makes sense now. Sorry I don't know the answer :(

Comment: @myfunkyside I realised right now that no matter where I click on my pages it raises the error. I think that modal is not the problem. I don't know what I changed to produced this error. I click on any button even the blank space of my page and F12 dev tools I see the error mentioned in the question. However this error doesn't stop to work with the page but it is annoying.

Comment: I recently installed some chrome extensiones like https everywhere, invisiblehand, noisi and a ads blocker. Hope is not of these extensions. I didn't restarted my chrome browser since then.

Comment: OMG it was an Chrome extension that I recently installed that produced the error. I uninstalled it and now I don't have any error.

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys that you take the time to comments.

Comment: Phew! The world can breath again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on your edit with a more concreat answer.

Yes, it was a Chrome extension causing that issue: InvisibleHand.

If you look inside that `ih.js` file you'll see the reference `invisiblehand` everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I remember to have installed Noisly, Invisible hand and HTTPS Everywhere and another that I don't remember. But I kept HTTPS only. Good to know that it was invisible hand.